# In react ,how to integrate immutableJS with Normalizr

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js, normalizr

We are considering having both immutableJS and Normalizr used in our project , but a number of challenges facing us wrap our head around.

1. When it comes to the state conversion, for instance, when an Ajax response from server arrives, should I convert the response to `immutableJS(Record,List,Map)` first or do `Normalize` with Normalizr first?
2. In order to enjoy the benefits, We have made up our mind using the immutableJS, but should immutableJS data shape (`immutableJS(Record,List,Map)`) be used throughout the entire react project (e.g all state in `Redux` & UI state in `Smart component`&`dumb component`&other `props`) 
   or just having it only used in `Redux` is fairly enough and Inside the react Component the plain object still should be used?

Answer (score 0):

I did not use Normalize, neither immutableJS. But how the self name says, immutableJS is to make the data be immutable.

1. So I think you must Normalize first and after make immutableJS.
2. I think you should use immutableJS at the entire project, because the react state variables shoud be immutable.

Comment: I appreciate your opinions , I wanna preferably normalize the state first before converting intoimmutableJS

Answer (score 0):

I am faced with the same decision and it seems normalizr first before immutable is saner but the problem with that is

1. I might lose access to normalizr functions especially if i want to perform linq-like or ramda actions on the immutable state
2. I might have to always use the forbidden .toJS at some points to get the data back to a normalizr form

I believe that with normalizr first approach and without worrying above the above dilemmas, things could still be done efficiently but that would only means that normalizr-ing is used in this case as only a schema definition library

What do you think?

A working example of normalizr-ing first approach [here](http://fullstackdeveloper.info/redux-state-with-immutable-js-normalizr-and-reselect/)

===========================================================================

This is what I would do

1. I would suggest you normalize first as that way you would have a prepared / defined data shape in your state. I do not know your response shape but I always advise that unless you have a deeply nested data or a almost schema-less data, there won't be any need for normalizr.
2. Once you decide to inject immutableJS into your application, you will have to be extra careful to restrict it within a particular scope. I would also suggest that you have it scoped within your redux state and your smart components UI state. You might want to avoid it when it comes to your dumb components though as those are basically for presentational purposes with little or no extra logics.

PS: I have a legacy project and I am trying to integrate ImmutableJS and normalizr into the code, since all my UI and redux states are pure JS objects, I decided to graft in an ImmutableJS shape into the redux tree managed by a combinedReducer. That gives me a single redux state with different reducer object types.

Comment: Sounds more like another question than an answer?

Comment: Hahaha! Let me rephrase the answer then.